# Do I need an online database if I am hosting docker webservice on AWS instance?

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I would like to deploy my web service on AWS EC2 instance. My plan is to install docker on AWS EC2.

My plan is to create an image of my web service and transfer the docker container to my AWS instance which will be able to host the web service since I have docker on my AWS instance.

My question:
If my web service is pulling data from my local DB. Does that mean that I have to create an AWS RDS to store all my data since my web service is running on EC2.

How does it work? Can anyone direct me to any guide that is available?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to pull from local machine you don't need to create a RDS database. Use Virtual Private Gateway to connect the VPC to your on-site systems over a secure VPN. You can also use direct connect in AWS

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm just wondering... If I were to pull from local machine, does my AWS EC2 instance requires WAMP/LAMP?